# Testing text in TextSpan

Tags: dart, flutter

If we have a `TextSpan` that is a child of a `RichText` widget, how would you test the text content.

```
new TextSpan(
  text: 'Hello world!',
  style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
)
```

In your tests, with a `Text` widget, you can use `expect(find.text('Hello world!'), findsOneWidget)`, but this doesn't work if you have a `TextSpan`.

`expect(find.byType(TextSpan), findsOneWidget)` also does not find any widgets of type `TextSpan`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's not possible. As `TextSpan` doesn't actually render anything.
It is data information used by another object to actually render something.

What you can do instead is to find the widget to which you pass your `TextSpan`. And then verify it's correct

Comment: how would you find the widget to which you pass the TextSpan (which is the RichText, correct)?

Comment: I answered my question from the comment by myself, see my answer to this question which clarifies Rémi's second point.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to Rémi's answer, here is the way to find the text from a `RichText`.
You set the key to the `RichText` and then you can do:

```
Finder widgetFinder = find.byKey(key);

Finder rtFinder =
   find.descendant(of: widgetFinder, matching: find.byType(RichText));
RichText richText = rtFinder.evaluate().first.widget as RichText;
String richTextText = richText.text.toPlainText();

print('Text from Text widget: $richTextText');
expect(richTextText, 'This is my text',
   reason: 'Text from found text widget do not match');
```

Answer (score 7):

It can be achieved by using `byWidgetPredicate`

```
expect(
    find.byWidgetPredicate((widget) =>
        widget is RichText &&
        widget.text.toPlainText() ==
            'Hello World!.'),
    findsOneWidget);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can find the RichText widget instead. Here's the find.byWidgetPredicate call.

```
expect(find.byWidgetPredicate((widget) => fromRichTextToPlainText(widget) == 'Hello world!'), findsOneWidget);
```

Here's the fromRichTextToPlainText helper function. Pass it the RichText widget, it will return the plain text for all the underlying TextSpans.

```
String fromRichTextToPlainText(final Widget widget) {
  if (widget is RichText) {
    if (widget.text is TextSpan) {
      final buffer = StringBuffer();
      (widget.text as TextSpan).computeToPlainText(buffer);
      return buffer.toString();
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From above snippets - I found below bit customised version helpful to me..

```
String? fromRichTextToPlainText(final Widget widget) {
  if (widget is RichText) {
    return widget.text.toPlainText();
  }
  return null;
}
```

```
expect(
          find.byWidgetPredicate(
              (widget) => fromRichTextToPlainText(widget) == 'My Rich Text'),
          findsOneWidget);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone needs to not just find the widget, but also tap on it:

[Finding a TextSpan to tap on with Flutter tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60247342/finding-a-textspan-to-tap-on-with-flutter-tests)