# Finding a TextSpan to tap on with Flutter tests

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

With a Flutter WidgetTester how can you tap on a TextSpan, like in the code below?

```
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    children: [
      TextSpan(text: 'aaa '),
      TextSpan(
        text: 'bbb ',
        recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
          ..onTap = () { 
            // How to reach this code in a widget test?
          },
      ),
      TextSpan(text: 'ccc'),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/testing/widget/tap-drag) tutorial didn't help you?

Comment: @P4yam, no because TextSpan is not a widget. But the accepted answer is great.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[CommonFinders byWidgetPredicate method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/CommonFinders/byWidgetPredicate.html)

[InlineSpan visitChildren method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/InlineSpan/visitChildren.html)

#### Find the TextSpan:

```
final finder = find.byWidgetPredicate(
  (widget) => widget is RichText && tapTextSpan(widget, "bbb "),
);
```

```
bool findTextAndTap(InlineSpan visitor, String text) {
  if (visitor is TextSpan && visitor.text == text) {
    (visitor.recognizer as TapGestureRecognizer).onTap();

    return false;
  }

  return true;
}

bool tapTextSpan(RichText richText, String text) {
  final isTapped = !richText.text.visitChildren(
    (visitor) => findTextAndTap(visitor, text),
  );

  return isTapped;
}
```

Comment: byWidgetPredicate method not found in FlutterDriver.

Comment: Not absolutely, but helped in understanding the flow.

Comment: I tried same, but worked for me was find the widget before `tester
      .widget<RichText>(find.byKey(<key>))` and then call the suggested `tapTextSpan(...)` function.

Comment: Here is a good workaround: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/56023#issuecomment-764985456