# Flutter WidgetTest cannot click on TextSpan

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

Very new to flutter WidgetTest and could not find a solution to a problem I am having. When dealing with TextSpan objects for WidgetTests, I'm unable to tap on the object.

UI Code

```
RichText(
    text: TextSpan(
        text: "First piece of text",

        children: [
        TextSpan(
            text: "Text I want to tap in widget text",
            
            recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                ..onTap = () {
                // go to another page i want to look for a text widget on
                }),
        ],
    ),
)
```

WidgetTest code

```
Future<void> textSpanTap(WidgetTester tester) async {
  await tester.pumpWidget(const MaterialApp(home: signInPage));
  await tester.tap(find.text("Text I want to tap in widget text"));
}
```

Any insight on this would help.

Comment: Take a new parent widget InkWell() or GestureDetector() and you can easily handle your onTap event.

Answer (score 0):

Initially I started with the similar question here: [Finding a TextSpan to tap on with Flutter tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60247342/finding-a-textspan-to-tap-on-with-flutter-tests)
.

But the solution from there proved to be non-reliable (worked, but for any configuration).

I ended up using the suggested workaround from here:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/56023#issuecomment-764985456